# Display the json images by order while tapping the button

Tags: ios

What i want is,i have five buttons,and i have to retrieve the five images(1,2,3,4,5)in json,after that if i have to tapping the first button means then display the images by 1,2,3,4,5 order,after selecting the second button means then display the images by 2,3,4,5,1 order,after selecting the third button means then display the images by 3,4,5,1,2 order,after selecting the fourth button means then display the images by 4,5,1,2,3 order,after selecting the fiveth button means then display the images by 5,1,2,3,4 order,thats all about my question,could you please guide me to done this operation,any solution for this much appreciated,thank you.

Comment: what does your JSON structure look like?

Comment: CODE:

[{
       “image1": “www.image1.com",
 “id": 1,
 
}, {
  “image2": “www.image2.com",
   “id": 2,

}, {
     “image3": “www.image3.com”,
  “id": 3,
  
}, {
  “image4": “www.image4.com",
  “id": 4,

}, {
  “image5": “www.image5.com",
 “id”:5,

}]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag your button to identify which button has been pressed and in your respective action, you need to retrieve the tag to identify the button that has been tapped. I will not describe you how to tag your button as you can get the answer from the stack overflow. But for the sake of this example, I am straight forward storing in images, you can retrieve and convert the response from JSON to respective array.

```
var images: [[String: AnyObject]] =  [
        [ "image1" : "www.image1.com", "id" : 1 ],
         [ "image2" : "www.image2.com", "id" : 2 ],
         [ "image4": "www.image4.com", "id" : 4 ],
         [ "image3": "www.image3.com", "id" : 3 ],
         [ "image5": "www.image5.com", "id" : 5 ]]
```

You need to sort the array once you have obtained it from the JSON as follow:

```
images.sort {($0["id"] as? Int ) < ($1["id"] as? Int)}
```

Once you have sorted array, you can implement the functionality to retrieve the array of image based on your requirement as shown below:

```
func imagesForButtonIndex(_ buttonIndex: Int) -> [[String: AnyObject]]   {
    var sortedImages = images.filter { ($0["id"] as? Int) >= buttonIndex}
    sortedImages.append(contentsOf:images.filter {($0["id"] as? Int) < buttonIndex})
    return sortedImages
}
```

calling

```
imagesForButtonIndex(5)
```

you will retrieve images as per requirements as shown below

[image]

Comment: hello idindu,i know only objective c,but in swift some codes only understand remaining things cannot be understand for me,so could you please explain this,i have to learn